# Sending Google Mails with OAuth but without consent screen

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

What we would like achieve right now, it's to send from some Google email addresses mails related to automatization in the product. So the client saves credentials in our application, generated by themself in Google Console, provides some email addresses and we can use them to send some automation emails without any additional client's steps. So clear server-to-server connection without accepting consent of separated Google users.

Right now we've tried Service Account with domain-wide delegation and it works. However the problem with this is that our server has access to all of the client's email addresses, and client cannot assign exactly which email addresses will be available (or can?). So if there will be a leak somewhere, email addresses can be used with this Service Account credentials.
It's possible with Microsoft Exchange to assign users to Service Account, but I don't see such option in Google.

Comment: You are approaching this wrong and I consider it a very bad idea. Create a Gmail account or O365, etc, and use that account to send emails to users. You do not need access to their account to send them emails.

Comment: Hey @JohnHanley for a response, but it's not what I'm looking for. I'm asking for technical knowledge about the Google Service Account, not a review of the architecture approach. First of all, it cannot be my company email address, it will be installed on the client's servers (there will be more customizable email addresses in different areas). It's an old product, we want to just modernize it. Also, we cannot use simple basic auth, this is a requirement to use a modern SMTP authentication mechanism. So here I'm asking for something like a Google Service Account with mail address restriction.

Comment: Nothing in your comment changes my first comment. Google Cloud does not offer a service to meet your requirements. What do you mean by modern SMTP authentication? Service accounts do not have email ability. In some cases they can impersonate another identity but in your case that is another security risk using domain wide delegation. Rethink what can be done.

Comment: I would not provide a vendor credentials that had domain wide delegation. The security risks and privacy issues are very high. As a vendor I would not want the risk.